# How to include GStreamer 1.0 in Gtk2

Tags: python

I am working in a pygtk project with Gtk2. As part of modification I need to include Gstreamer 1.0 instead of 0.1. In my old system can use

```
import sys, os, os.path, time
import pygst
pygst.require("0.1")
import gst
```

But I don't know how to add new version of GStreamer ...  I try above one with
change in version as

```
 import sys, os, os.path, time
 import pygst
 pygst.require("1.0")
 import gst
```

but got error as

> pygst.require("1.0")   File
>   "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pygst.py", line 57, in require
>       raise RequiredVersionError, "Only version '%s' is available" % _pygst_version pygst.RequiredVersionError: Only version '0.10' is available

Please advise how can include new version fine...

Answer (score 1):

You can't use GStreamer 1.x in Python together with the old GTK2 Python bindings. GStreamer 1.x uses a newer version of pygobject than what pygtk2 requires, and they both conflict and unfortunately the GTK team did not release a pygtk2 version that works with the newer pygobject although they're still maintaining GTK2.

You'll have to upgrade to GTK3 at the same time as updating to GStreamer 1.x.